# Can't print data obtained from parsing JSON

Tags: php, json, decode

I created this JSON data:

```
{
  "status" : "fail",
  "data" : {
    "error_message" : "Label already exists on your account for Network."
  }
}
```

The code in my PHP page is:

```
$newaddr = json_decode($json, true);
echo $newaddr->status;
echo $newaddr->data;
```

and the result I get when I run it is:

> fail

How can I show the value of `error_message` in my page? Because:

```
$newaddr->data
```

has the value `null` when I print it using `var_dump($newaddr->data);`

Answer (score 2):

When you use `json_decode(..., true);` the second parameter means that you want to json to be parsed as associative arrays. But, you are trying to get the data by object property.

The solutions are:

1. Change the second parameter to false

   ```
   $newaddr = json_decode($json, false);
   echo $newaddr->status;
   echo $newaddr->data->error_message;
   ```
2. Get data with array-way

   ```
   $newaddr = json_decode($json, true);
   echo $newaddr['status'];
   echo $newaddr['data']['error_message'];
   ```

[json_decode documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Tried your both answer, but still got blank as the result.

Comment: Works fine here: https://www.tehplayground.com/PXJuU94o5lN1y6er.
Maybe the json is not properly encoded? Try to show some more code